# Break full script based on an if statement in a nested loop

Tags: powershell

I have a very long script, within this script I am doing some validation for some input gathered from a csv files. So the script will first import the CSV files and then read them and based on some condition it will excite a part of the script. This part of the script will perform some validation and to perform them correctly I have to do a loop within a loop. If this validation was not successful then the script will print an error and then break.

The problem is that the script is not breaking.

I understand that the Break will break only the current loop or an outer loop if you have identified a label to the outer loop and called this label in the break command.

What I need is if this validation was not successful in the nested loop then the whole script should break and also not to exit as I would need to leave the console running.

For example in the below you will find loop running against values in the variable called vSphereNSXEnvironmentInfo. this variable is holding the info imported from one of the CSV file. These info is related to the FQDN, Username and passwords for NSX, vCenter server and Hosting vCenter Server (PS you can ignore the NSX bit over here I am just concentrating on the vCenter info) and this CSV file will hold these info for each site.

an example for the info included in this variable would be:

```
SiteName                              : CGSM-Site
NsxManagerFqdn                        : CGSM-NSX.nfv.gss
NsxManagerUser                        : admin
NsxManagerPassword                    : VMware1!
vCenterFqdn                           : CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss
vCenterUser                           : administrator@vsphere.local
vCenterPassword                       : VMware1!
vCenterHostingNsxFqdn                 : CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss
vCenterHostingNsxUser                 : administrator@vsphere.local
vCenterHostingNsxPassword             : VMware1!
vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn             : CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss
vCenterHostingvCenterUser             : administrator@vsphere.local
vCenterHostingvCenterPassword         : VMware1!
PrimaryNsxManagerFQDN                 : NotUsed
PrimaryNsxManagerUser                 : NotUsed
PrimaryNsxManagerPassword             : NotUsed
vCenterRegisteredToPrimaryNsxFQDN     : NotUsed
vCenterRegisteredToPrimaryNsxUser     : NotUsed
vCenterRegisteredToPrimaryNsxPassword : NotUsed
NsxController1IP                      : 192.168.4.61
NsxController2IP                      : 192.168.4.62
NsxController3IP                      : 192.168.4.63
NsxControllersPassword                : VMware1!VMware1!

SiteName                              : CGSR-Site
NsxManagerFqdn                        : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
NsxManagerUser                        : admin
NsxManagerPassword                    : VMware1!
vCenterFqdn                           : CGSR-VCSA.nfv.gss
vCenterUser                           : administrator@vsphere.local
vCenterPassword                       : VMware1!
vCenterHostingNsxFqdn                 : CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss
vCenterHostingNsxUser                 : administrator@vsphere.local
vCenterHostingNsxPassword             : VMware1!
vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn             : CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss
vCenterHostingvCenterUser             : administrator@vsphere.local
vCenterHostingvCenterPassword         : VMware1!
PrimaryNsxManagerFQDN                 : CGSM-NSX.nfv.gss
PrimaryNsxManagerUser                 : admin
PrimaryNsxManagerPassword             : VMware1!
vCenterRegisteredToPrimaryNsxFQDN     : CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss
vCenterRegisteredToPrimaryNsxUser     : administrator@vsphere.local
vCenterRegisteredToPrimaryNsxPassword : VMware1!
NsxController1IP                      : 192.168.4.61
NsxController2IP                      : 192.168.4.62
NsxController3IP                      : 192.168.4.63
NsxControllersPassword                : VMware1!VMware1!
```

In the below Script you will find the process as follow:

1- Run a For Loop for each bunch of info in the variable.

2- First validation will check for connectivity and to do so I am creating another For Loop for a created PS-Object adding the required destination to check the connectivity to. If Connection test fails then it will Break

3- Second Validation will check for the username and password and to do so I am creating another For Loop for a created PS-Object adding the required destination to check the connectivity to. If username and password is not correct then it will Break

4- Third Validation will check for Registration.

And scripts goes on and on. so when I intentionally give a wrong username and password in the CSV file, the code reach to this level and error out as expected but it will break from the inner loop and going to the outer loop which is also expected.

What I need is to break from the whole script.

Code:

```
#region ######### - 2nd Sub-Sub-Section - SubSubSectionName: CheckIfNoNsxIsInUse.

###########################################
#######    Start of SubSubSection    ######
###########################################

#SubSection Description:    This SubSubsection will check and validate the info gathered from the vSphere-NSX-Required-Info.csv file with respect to the IP/FQDN connectivity as well as the credentials if the NSX is Not in use.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Gray "           NSX-v is not used, Checking credentials and connection to vCenter Server only."     

    Foreach ($Line in $vSphereNSXEnvironmentInfo) {                     

        Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Gray "           Working on Site " $Line.SiteName " For " $Line.vCenterFqdn "."

        #region ££££££££££££ - 1st Sub-Sub-Sub-Section - SubSubSubSectionName: CheckConnectivity.

            ###########################################
            #######    Start of SubSubSection    ######
            ###########################################

            #SubSubSubSection Description:  This SubSubSubsection will check Connectivity.
            #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

            #Check Connectivity for vCenter Servers in each provided site in the vSphere-NSX-Required-Info.csv


            #Test Connection for the endpoint and the hosting endpoint over port 22 and 443.
            Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Gray "           Checking connection over port 22 and 443."      

            #Create an array and add 22 and 443 in it to loop over it to make it easier for the code instead of writing the code twice once for 22 and another for 443
            $RequiredPorts = @("22","443")
            Foreach ($Port in $RequiredPorts) {
                #Create an array with the FQDN of the End point and check of the hosting vCenter is the same and if not then add it to the array.
                #Reason of creating this array is to minimize the code by running a loop for this array rather than writing the code 4 times once for each endpoint.
                $EndPoints = @()
                $EndPoints += $Line.vCenterFqdn
                If ($Line.vCenterFqdn -NE $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn) {$EndPoints += $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn}                      
                Foreach ($Target in $EndPoints) {
                    $TestConnection = Test-NetConnection -Port $Port -ComputerName $Target
                    If ($TestConnection.PingSucceeded -Eq "True") {
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:DarkYellow "             Connection to "$Target " over port " $Port " is successful."
                    }
                        Else {
                            Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Connection to "$Target " over port " $Port " is not successful."
                            Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Please check connectivity to endpoints and try again."
                            start-sleep 5
                            Break
                        }               
                    }
            }


        ###########################################
        #######   End of SubSubSubSection     #####
        ########################################### 

        #---------------------------------------------- 

    #endregion

    #-----------------------------------------

    #region ££££££££££££ - 2nd Sub-Sub-Sub-Section - SubSubSubSectionName: CheckValidityOfUsername&Password.

        ###########################################
        #######    Start of SubSubSection    ######
        ###########################################

        #SubSubSubSection Description:  This SubSubSubsection will check Validity of Username and Passwords.
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        #Check validity of usernames and passwords for each NSX/vCneter EndPoint in each provided site in the vSphere-NSX-Required-Info.csv

        Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Gray "           Checking gathered Username and Passwords for all vCenter Servers."  


        #Create an HashTable with the FQDN, Username and Password for each Endpoint and then add the HashTable to an Array Variable to have all Endpoints info.
        #Reason of creating this array is to minimize the code by running a loop for this array rather than writing the code once for each endpoint.

        #Create the Variable, Note that the Hashtable will be created each time the tool go to another endpoint to delete the priviouse info of the priviouse endpoint.
        $EndPointsArray = @()

        #1- Add Working vCenter Server to the HashTable
        $EndPointsHashTable = @{}
        $URL = "https://" + $Line.vCenterFqdn + "/rest/com/vmware/cis/session"
        $EndPointsHashTable.add("Description", "vCenter")
        $EndPointsHashTable.add("EndPoint", $Line.vCenterFqdn)
        $EndPointsHashTable.add("URI", $URL)
        $Header = vCenterAuthurization -Username $Line.vCenterUser -Password $Line.vCenterPassword
        $EndPointsHashTable.add("Header", $Header)
        $EndPointsArray += $EndPointsHashTable

        #2- Add vCneter Server VM Hosting vCenter Server to the HashTable if exists.
        If ($Line.vCenterFqdn -NE $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn) {
            $URL = "https://" + $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn + "/rest/com/vmware/cis/session"
            $EndPointsHashTable.add("Description", "vCenter")
            $EndPointsHashTable.add("EndPoint", $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn)
            $EndPointsHashTable.add("URI", $URL)
            $Header = vCenterAuthurization -Username $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterUser -Password $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterPassword
            $EndPointsHashTable.add("Header", $Header)
            $EndPointsArray += $EndPointsHashTable
        }


        #Run the llop for the gathered info in the EndPointsArray Array Variable and validate the Username and Password.
        Foreach ($EndPoint in $EndPointsArray) {

            #Check if it is a Controller and if yes then use the Push-SSH.
            If ($EndPoint.Description -Eq "Controller") {
            $TestCredentials = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $EndPoint.URI -Credential $EndPoint.Header -AcceptKey
                If ($TestCredentials) {Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:DarkYellow "              Username and Password for " $EndPoint.URI " are successful."}
                Else {
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Provided Username and Password for " $EndPoint.URI " are incorrect."
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Please check Username and Password and try again."
                    start-sleep 5
                    Break
                }
            }

            #Run the validation for the rest normally as there will be nothing else that will need to use Push-SSH rathere than Invoke-WebRequest.
            $TestCredentials = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $EndPoint.URI -Method Post -Headers $head
            If ($TestCredentials.StatusCode -Eq 200) {Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:DarkYellow "               Username and Password for " $EndPoint.URI " are successful."}
                Else {
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Provided Username and Password for " $EndPoint.URI " are incorrect."
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Please check Username and Password and try again."
                    start-sleep 5
                    Break
                }
            }


        ###########################################
        #######   End of SubSubSubSection     #####
        ########################################### 

    #---------------------------------------------- 

#endregion

#-----------------------------------------                      

#region ££££££££££££ - 3rd Sub-Sub-Sub-Section - SubSubSubSectionName: CheckHostingvCenterServers.

    ###########################################
    #######    Start of SubSubSection    ######
    ###########################################

    #SubSubSubSection Description:  This SubSubSubsection will Check and validate the hosting vCenterServer.
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------              

    #Check if the Hosting vCenter Server are correct.

    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Gray "           Validating Hosting vCenter for vCenter VM"  

    #Second will check if vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn field is not set to NotUsed which would indicate that there are are a Hosting vCenter.
    #If vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn is set to a value other than NotUsed, Connect and try to locate the NSX Manager VM.
    #If vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn is set to NotUsed then Connect to the Working vCenter and Locate the NSX Manaver VM.
    If ($Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn -NE "NotUsed") {

        Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Gray "           Another hosting vCenter for vCenter is detected in csv file, confirmting info." 

        #At this point there is a hosting vCenter to the NSX, Connect and try to locate.
        $HostingvCenterforWorkingvCenterConnection = Connect-VIServer -Server $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn -User $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterUser -Password $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterPassword -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction Ignore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If ($HostingvCenterforWorkingvCenterConnection) {
            #Convert Working NSX Manager FQDN to IP to be used in locating the VM.
            $vCenterIpConverted = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($Line.vCenterFqdn)
            $LocatevCenterVM = Get-VM -Server $HostingvCenterforWorkingvCenterConnection | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Guest.Nics.IPAddress -contains "$vCenterIpConverted" } 
            Disconnect-VIServer -Server $HostingvCenterforWorkingvCenterConnection -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
            If ($LocatevCenterVM) {
                Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:DarkYellow "             " $Line.vCenterFqdn " is confirmed to be Hosted on " $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn "."
            }
                Else {
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                " $Line.vCenterFqdn " VM could not be found on " $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn "."
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Data Provided are incorrect, please check and try again."
                    start-sleep 5
                    Break
                }
            }
                Else {
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Unable to connect to " $Line.vCenterHostingvCenterFqdn "."
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Please check and try again."
                    start-sleep 5
                    Break
                }
            }
                Else {

                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Gray "           No additional hosting vCenter is detected in csv file, confirmting info."   

                    #At this point there are no additional hosting vCenter are detected, which means that the NSX is hosted on vCenterFqdn, Connect and try to locate..
                    $HostingvCenterforWorkingvCenterConnection = Connect-VIServer -Server $Line.vCenterFqdn -User $Line.vCenterUser -Password $Line.vCenterPassword -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction Ignore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    If ($HostingvCenterforWorkingvCenterConnection) {
                        #Convert Working NSX Manager FQDN to IP to be used in locating the VM.
                        $vCenterIpConverted = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($Line.vCenterFqdn)
                        $LocateNsxVM = Get-VM -Server $HostingvCenterforWorkingvCenterConnection | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Guest.Nics.IPAddress -contains "$vCenterIpConverted" } 
                        Disconnect-VIServer -Server $HostingvCenterforWorkingvCenterConnection -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
                        If ($LocateNsxVM) {
                            Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:DarkYellow "             " $Line.vCenterFqdn " is confirmed to be Hosted on " $Line.vCenterFqdn "."
                        }
                            Else {
                                Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                " $Line.vCenterFqdn " VM could not be found on " $Line.vCenterFqdn "."
                                Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Data Provided are incorrect, please check and try again."
                                start-sleep 5
                                Break
                            }
                    }
                        Else {
                            Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Unable to connect to " $Line.vCenterFqdn "."
                            Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "                Please check and try again."
                            start-sleep 5
                            Break
                        }

                }
                #----------------------------------------------------------------               


    ###########################################
    #######   End of SubSubSubSection     #####
    ########################################### 

    #---------------------------------------------- 

#endregion

#-----------------------------------------


} #End of rht Foreach Loop started at the begining.

    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:DarkGreen "                  All dtat in vSphere-NSX-Required-Info.csv file was validated."  

    ###########################################
    #######    End of SubSubSection      ######
    ########################################### 

    #---------------------------------------------- 

#endregion
```

Comment: [I'd suggest reading this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flow control statements in PowerShell (like `foreach` loops) support *labels*, in the form `:labelname`, like so:

```
:outer
foreach($Array in @(@(1,2),@(3,4),@(5,6))){
    :inner
    foreach($Value in $Array){
        Write-Host $Value
        if($Value -eq 1){
            break inner
        }
        if($Value -eq 4){
            break outer
        }
    }    
}
```

In the example above, the first `if` condition in the inner loop will skip only the value `2`, whereas the second `if` condition will skip everything else because the `break` instruction applies to the `outer` loop.

Notice that the `:` is *not* part of the label name, so `break inner` breaks the loop preceded by `:inner` (thanks to [mklement0 for pointing it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502920/break-full-script-based-on-an-if-statement-in-a-nested-loop/51503323?noredirect=1#comment89976329_51503323))

Comment: Just as a point on style, you can also prefix the labels to the statement (e.g. `:loop foreach (`).  I actually wasn't aware they could be on their own line.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes, that's quite deliberate (I hate the sight of arbitrary labels in front of my statements)

Comment: Another perhaps non-obvious behavior: the `:` mustn't be used when _referencing_ a label; e.g., `break inner` works, but `break :inner` doesn't (the operand is simply _ignored_) - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5724, which suggests optionally allowing the use of  `:`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you for your help, Did not know that you can actually that you can add the label outside the loop itself, what I did is that I added the label outside the main loop and also in the IF/Else statement if the loop should break I also added a variable containing 1 and after the loop I check if this variable exists and if yes then I will break the whole script.